# How to remove AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions from AVAudioSessionCategory?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiosession

I set my `AVAudioSessionCategory` like this with options:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Later in my Code **I want to remove `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers`** from the `AVAudioSessionCategory`.

According to documentation this should do the trick:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

However it does not work in iOS 9 and iOS 10. It does not throw any error, but the option is not removed. I already reported this as a bug to Apple.

As long as this is not fixed: Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Please keep in mind: Working with `AVAudioSessionCategory` can only be tested on a real device.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

It does not work while the app is in background though.